# How to implement WebRTC recording to Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webrtc, video-recording

I would like to create an easy video blogging solution utilizing WebRTC technology to enable recording of video/audio directly from the browser, similar to Youtube's My_Webcam. The server component should be based on Node.js.

I found some Node.js libraries for general WebRTC connection managment ([webRTC.io](https://github.com/cavedweller/webRTC.io), [Holla](https://github.com/wearefractal/holla), EasyRTC), but it seems they don't enable recording of streams on the server.

What's the best way to implement server-side recording? Are there libraries and tutorials available?

Comment: according to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=E8C8ouiXHHk#t=2339 it's not trivial. You have to use the C++ library and open a PeerConnection to the Server.

Comment: @bluepuma Have you found a solution for your problem? I am also interested in saving streams on server.

Comment: you can use node-webrtc lib for server side stream receiving. But node-webrtc is not well documented. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This guy has a ton of interesting WebRTC experiments, including audio/video recording: https://github.com/muaz-khan/

Here's a demo of recording: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection-v1.4-Demos/RecordRTC-and-RTCMultiConnection.html

It collects the audio and video streams on the client and gives you a blob of audio and a blob of video that you can then upload/splice together.

Not exactly what you were hoping for, I think, but could probably get the job done. Hope that helps.

Comment: But this is not supported in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You may use node-webkit to achieve this. Node webkit is essentially a browser in node.js.

Comment: This is not how it should be done. It's perfectly possible to record a stream using a script processor node of the remote stream and send each PCM sample to a remote node server.

Comment: @user427390 you are right for audio recordings, but this is not possible for video recording