# how to perform continuous speech to text on webrtc communication audio stream in mobile app

Tags: react-native, webrtc, web-audio-api, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am trying to add a continuous speech to text recognizer in a mobile application during a webrtc audio-only call.

I'm using react native on the mobile side, with the [react-native-webrtc module](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc) and a custom web api for the signaling part. I've got the hand of the web api, so I am able to add the feature on it's side if it's the only solution, but I prefer to perform it on the client side to avoid consuming bandwidth if there is no need.

First, I have worked and tested some ideas with my laptop browser. My first idea, was to use the SpeechRecognition interface from the webspeechapi : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition

I have merged [the audio only webrtc demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio/) with the [audiovisualiser demonstration](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/webaudio-output/) in one page but there, I did not find how to connect a `mediaElementSourceNode` (created via `AudioContext.createMediaElementSource(remoteStream)` at line 44 of [streamvisualizer.js](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/js/third_party/streamvisualizer.js)) to a web_speech_api `SpeechRecognition` class. In the Mozilla documentation, the audio stream seems to came with the constructor of the class, which may call the `getUserMedia()` api.

Second, during my researches I have found two open source speech to text engine : [cmusphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/) and [mozilla's deep-speech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech). The first one have a [js binding](https://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/) and seems great with the `audioRecoder` that I can feed with my own `mediaElementSourceNode` from the first try. However, how to embed this in my react native application?

There are also Android and iOS natives webrtc modules, which I may be able to connect with cmusphinx platform specific bindings ([iOS](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-ios-demo), [Android](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/)) but I don't know about native classes inter-operability. Can you help me with that?

I haven't already created any "grammar" or define "hot-words" because I am not sure of technologies involved, but I can do it latter if I am able to connect a speech recognition engine to my audio stream.

Comment: may i ask, how have you solved it? I am working on a similar project, don't know how to combine Speech Recognition with web calls, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stream the audio to the ASR server by either adding [another webrtc party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987973/how-to-implement-webrtc-recording-to-node-js-server?rq=1) on the call or by some other protocol (TCP/Websocket/etc). On the server you perform recognition and send results back.

> First, I have worked and tested some ideas with my laptop browser. My first idea, was to use the SpeechRecognition interface from the webspeechapi : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition

This is experimental and does not really work in Firefox. In Chrome it only takes microphone input directly, not dual stream from caller and callee.

> The first one have a js binding and seems great with the audioRecoder that I can feed with my own mediaElementSourceNode from the first try.

You will not be able to run this as local recognition inside your react native app

Comment: About the mediaElementSourceNode audioRecorder solution based, why I won't be able to run it inside a react native app ? event with a webview ?

Comment: It will be too slow to transcribe anything serious. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949295/cmusphinx-pocketsphinx-recognize-all-or-large-amount-of-words

Comment: I have not been precise enough, here is the new post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102224/does-react-native-webview-can-perform-webrtc-call-audio-hot-keywords-speech-to with an update about my experimentations !